# ViewController has too many line of code (options for refactoring)

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, refactoring

My ViewController looks really huge and has 500+ lines of code now.
I'd like to refactor it and put some methods into external classes or categories.

But a lot of my methods deal with IBOutlets or UIViewAnimation, animating Storyboard's View elements, hiding them, changing opacity, etc.

What's the best way to move such methods out of my ViewController?

```
- (void)animateBeforeNewRound;
- (void)animateBeforeNewGame;
- (void)animateBeforeFinishingTheGame;
- (void)presentSlidingView;

- (void)presentSlidingView {
    //preparing view constraint for animation
    __block float constr = 0;
    [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        if (constraint.firstItem == self.slideView && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) {
            constr = constraint.constant;
            [constraint setConstant:0.0f];
        }
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        /* animate prepared constraint */
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        /* animate constraints */
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
            self.imgBubble.alpha = 1;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            /* update constraints back to initial value */
            [self.view.constraints enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                if (constraint.firstItem == self.slide && constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) {
                    [constraint setConstant:constr];
                }
            }];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 delay:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
                [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                self.imgBubble.alpha = 0;
            }];
        }];
    }];
}
```

`- (void)animate*` methods look pretty similar to `- (void)presentSlidingView` and manipulate with the other Storyboard's IBOutlets.

Comment: Try to make a custom superclass to your viewController

Comment: @NJGadhiya Isn't it weird if your VC with the main logic subclasses from the VC which implements additional methods?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a good idea to use separate objects for handling separate tasks. For instance, you could create an `Animator` class which would handle all your `-(void)animateXX` methods.

You could do the same for handling delegates. I usually use a custom instance to handle all the `UITableViewDataSource` methods, as it makes my Table View Controller class less cluttered.

Separation of concerns is also great for future maintainability (e.g.: when you have an animation related problem, you'll know that the first place to look is your Animator).

[Here](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/table-views.html) is a great article on the matter.

Comment: Great! :) If you want, I actually have examples on my Github, for instance [JVRBaseTableViewDatasource](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/JVRBaseTableViewDataSource)

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion for particular function:

1. Create outlets for constraints and don't search for them in code explicitly, it would be much easier (as for me) to write something like that:

   `self.slideViewLeadingConstraint.Constant = 0.0f;`
2. Create helper functions for animations;

Try using [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) and/or [ReactiveAnimation](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveAnimation), I think it's really helps separating all those chaining calls and code looks neater;

Comment: Although ReactiveCocoa introduces new concepts which could certainly lead to a cleaner, more reasonable codebase, it won't solve the clutter by itself. I think the key takeaway here is the importance of proper separation of concerns. Ignore it, and you'll end up with 1000+ lines of unmaintainable View Controller code (and most of it won't belong there).